# Вошли с двумя дамами или с двоими дамами?

Tags: числительные

Правильно ли я строю предложение: Вошли с двумя дамами в кафе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***Вошли с двумя дамами в кафе.***

У собирательных числительных (двое, трое и др.) ограниченная сочетаемость с существительными – в частности, они не могут относиться к лицам женского пола.

[§167. Употребление собирательных числительных](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm)

Однако интересно то, что входить в кафе ***с двоими кавалерами*** тоже нежелательно, так как собирательные числительные **в косвенных падежах** (кроме И.п. и В.п.) **рекомендуется заменять**  количественными числительными.

**Дополнительный материал по теме** (с учебного сайта [Проза.ру](https://proza.ru/2021/07/20/1076))

РАЗДЕЛ 9. ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ ПО ТЕМАМ
ТЕМА 3. ОСОБЕННОСТИ СОЧЕТАЕМОСТИ С СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫМИ  ДЛЯ СОБИРАТЕЛЬНЫХ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫХ

1. ВЫБОР МЕЖДУ СОБИРАТЕЛЬНЫМИ И КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННЫМИ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМИ
   Так как допускаются оба сочетания вида *два друга – двое друзей* – с количественными и собирательными числительными, то возникает вопрос о выборе одного из вариантов.

ВЫБОР 1: Одушевленные существительные м. р. 1-го скл. с окончанием А обычно соединяются с собирательными числительными: трое юношей, трое мужчин (нежелательно: три юноши, три мужчины).

ВЫБОР 2: В некоторых случаях собирательные числительные не используются, так как они вносят сниженный оттенок значения: два профессора, три генерала (не следует говорить: двое профессоров, трое генералов).

ВЫБОР 3. В косвенных падежах желательно использовать не собирательные, а количественные числительные: с двумя друзьям, с тремя мальчиками, к трём мальчикам (нежелательно говорить: с двоими друзьями, троими мальчиками).
Я С ДВУМЯ ДРУЗЬЯМИ снял дом.
Требуется гувернантка К ТРЕМ мальчикам.